# Track activity in deployed AppStore iOS apps

Tags: debugging, compiled-language

I want to know what is going on in the apps on my iPhone when I press a button or trigger an action of any kind and see what it is doing with my data. Is there a way to track the activity of an app from the AppStore on my iPhone even if decompiling the app isn’t a possibility? As a beginner app developer having completed my first complete app I am very curious of how these things work.